# ¿Cuál es el problema en el a.replace() del siguiente código?

Tags: javascript, bucle-for, replace

Tengo que cambiar la letra por el índice de la cadena `b` de la misma letra. El problema es que se me bloquea en el navegador como si no se cumpliese jamás la condición del `for`.

¿Por qué pasa eso en el siguiente código?

```js
var a = "Hola";
a = a.toLowerCase();     
var b ="0abcdefghijklmopqrstuvwxyz";       
for(i = 0; i < a.length; i++){   
    var c = a.charAt(i);   
    a = a.replace(c,    
    (b.indexOf(c)).toString());  
}  
document.write(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que si la posición del caracter en la otra cadena es -1 (no existe) o mayor que 9, se remplaza por dos caracteres, incrementando la longitud de `a`, por ejemplo:

```
// En la primera iteración (i = 0) se remplaza h por 8
a = '8ola'
// En la segunda (i = 1) se remplaza o por 14 (creo)
a = '814la'
// En la siguiente (i = 2) no se toma la l, sino 4
// como el caracter no existe en b, indexOf() devuelve -1
a = '81-1la
// Luego, cuando i es igual a 3, el cuarto caracter es 1
// tampoco existe en b
a = '81--1la
```

La cadena se va incrementando y nunca va a llegar al final del ciclo.

**Solución:** Crea una nueva cadena vacía y ve agregando la posición de cada caracter.

```js
var a = "Hola";
a = a.toLowerCase();
var b ="0abcdefghijklmopqrstuvwxyz";
// Crear cadena vacía
let str = '';
for(i = 0; i < a.length; i++){   
    var c = a.charAt(i);
    // Concatenar la posición de c
    str += b.indexOf(c);
}
// Mostrar resultado
document.write(str);
```